# Is possible to copy only the log of commits to another project with git? What about discarding old changes to decrease the size of the .git folder?

Tags: git, logging, project, git-commit

I had many binary files in my git project. Due to this and the changes I have made, I had a huge `.git` folder. So I would like to create another project without these binary files and keep the logs and dates of all the commits.

I won't need to come back to a previous version of the project. So I don't care if I lose all the changes I've made because I will keep the old project if I need to check anything.

Is possible to achieve this? If not is there a way to decrease the size of the `.git` folder discarding old changes?

Comment: The history (log of commits) *is* (are?) the commits in the repository. You will need to make up a new history, using the existing commits as the source for the new ones, but omit the large binary files from the new copies. This will temporarily *increase* the size of your repository, but once all is done, you can throw away the original. The easiest way to achieve that is usually by cloning the post-filtering repository, but see also "BFG".

Comment: OK thanks @torek, I will check if those solutions work well for me